# How to share a bunch of files at once in iOS

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I need to share some data, e.g. two images, to other apps like dropbox or gdrive.

Some recommend using `UIActivityViewController` but there's no option for mimetypes and other recommend using `UIDocumentInteractionController` but this seems only be suitable for single files...

Does anybody know about the right way and/or can provide some example in swift?

**Edit:**

`UIActivityViewController` seems to be the right way and `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)` provides the content.
But what about files stored on a server? Those must be downloaded at some point during share process (e.g. after choosing dropbox). How can I achieve this? I tried with a customized `UIActivityItemSource` with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UIActivityViewController` is the right way.
I had to provide my files wrapped in a subclass of `UIActivityItemProvider`.

Overriding `item()`-function for downloading and providing my binary content.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Apple doc for [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to be another interesting way sharing some data between apps but I think it wouldn't be suitable for huge images...